# Similar to how there's field lines that make equations in Newtonian Gravity more intuitive, is there something that makes GR equations more intuitive?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, geometry, spacetime-dimensions, intuition

One way I know to get intuition for the derivation of the force equation $$F=\frac{GM_1M_2}{r^2}$$ in Newtonian Mechanics is to imagine gravitational field lines, in combination with certain symmetries.  When imagining gravitational field lines it's useful to think of them as straight half lines, that end on a massive body, in one direction, and being endless in the other direction.  When thinking of a massive sphere, or uniform density, it's useful, and intuitive, to think of the gravitational field lines as being evenly distributed around the surface of the massive sphere.  It's also useful, and intuitive, to consider all massive bodies, of the same, mass to produce the same number of gravitational field lines, and for the number of gravitational field lines that a massive body, of constant mass, to remain the same through time.  It's also useful, and intuitive, to think of two massive bodies gaining some amount of momentum, towards each other, for every instance that one mass intersects a gravitational field line of the other mass, with the gain in momentum being the same for every intersection, and being only in the direction towards the other mass.  Even if I pretend that I had never heard of the concept of a force, I could still consider how the rate that two massive bodies interest each others field lines is proportional as the rate that their momentums change, and so still arrive at a conclusion that is equivalent to the force being proportional to the density of the field lines even if using different terminology.

I find that thinking about field lines is more intuitive and easier to understand than starting with the force equation in Newtonian Gravity, and if I'm not mistaken thinking of the gravitational field lines in the way described is enough for a derivation of the basic form of the force equation.  If I imagine there being multiple massive bodies, of the same mass, evenly distributed within a spherical region, then the number of field lines that the spherical region produces is equal to the number of field lines a single mass produces multiplied by the number of masses in the sphere, which implies that the strength of a gravitational field is proportional to the mass producing it.  I can also consider that if either mass is increased by a factor of n then the other mass will intersect n times more gravitational field lines from it, implying that increasing either mass by a factor of n increases the force by a factor of n and so also implying that the force is proportional to the product of the two masses.  I can also consider that if there is a sphere centered on a mass, and containing only that mass, then, because the number of field lines on the sphere does not depend on its surface area, the density of field lines on the surface of the sphere is inversely proportional to the surface area of the sphere, and because the surface area of the sphere is proportional to the square of its radius, the density of the field lines on the surface area of the sphere is proportional to the inverse square of its radius.  This implies that the force between two bodies is proportional to the inverse square of the distance between them.

I understand that when considering very strong gravitational fields, or when two objects are moving close to the speed of light relative to each other General Relativity is needed to describe the gravitational interaction between the two bodies.  I understand that in General Relativity gravity is space time curvature rather than a force.  I have seen analogies for spacetime curvature involving balls creating dimples on a sheet, however the analogies of spacetime curvature involving objects on sheets don't help with figuring what equations describe spacetime curvature, which is different from how analogies using field lines do help with deriving the equation describing force in Newtonian Physics.  I understand that gravity in General Relativity is spacetime curvature, not just curvature in space, and analogies using objects on a sheet give the false impression that masses are simply rolling down hill in a curved space.  I also know that in General relativity there's the Schwarzschild Metric

$$g=-c^2d\tau^2=-\left(1-\frac{2GM}{rc^2}\right)c^2dt^2+\frac{dr^2}{1-\frac{2GM}{rc^2}}+r^2d\theta^2+sin^2{\theta}d\phi^2$$

which while more fundamental than the force equation in Newtonian Physics, I find it also more difficult to understand exactly where the equation comes from beyond the obvious explanation of, "It just makes the most accurate predictions," or "It's implied by the field equations," and I think using a derivation for an equation within the theory the equation is used for can help with intuition more than simply saying, "The equation makes the most accurate predictions."  One reason I mention this is that knowing the derivation of Newtonian Force equations means its easy to see how it changes in different numbers of dimensions, while not knowing the derivation of the Schwarzschild Metric means I can't tell how it would be different in different numbers of dimensions.

I'm thinking that maybe in lower dimensions, such as in $1+1$ dimensions, $0+2$ dimensions, or $2+0$ dimensions, it might be more intuitive to understand how to derive equations in GR than in $3+1$ dimensional spacetime.  I mean it is much easier to visualize something like $2+0$ or $0+2$ dimensions than to visualize $3+1 dimensions$, which I'm thinking could help with intuition.

I've wondered whether in $1+1$ dimensions in the presence of a massive body there would be a gravitational field that's uniform on either side of the massive body, no gravitational field, or a different type of geometry.  I've heard it said that accelerating at a constant rate in flat spacetime is equivalent to standing still in a gravitational field, which given that a massive body must stand still relative to itself, would gives the impression that if in $1+1$ dimensions, in the presence of a massive body there is a uniform gravitational field on either side of the massive body, then to inertial reference frames the mass would appear to accelerate at a constant rate, although one side of the massive body it would appear to accelerate one way, and on the other side it would appear to accelerate the other way.

Thinking about in the case of $0+2$ or $2+0$ dimensions, the world line of an object accelerating at a constant rate through flat spacetime would trace out a semi circle through spacetime, and eventually reach the same point in spacetime it started out at.  This gives the impression that if in $0+2$ or $2+0$ dimensions accelerating through empty space is equivalent to standing still in a uniform gravitational field, then if in the presence of the massive body there is a uniform gravitational field, because the massive body must stand still relative to itself, it's world line must also be a circle.  I was also wondering if in $0+2$ or $2+0$, in the presence of a massive body, spacetime might either be spherical or hyperbolic, with the positive or negative curvature determined by the mass given how both spherical and hyperbolic geometry have uniform curvature and have the property, in which all points are equivalent.  I'm not sure though whether in $0+2$ or $2+1$ the equations describing spacetime geometry in the presence of a massive body would be more intuitive to find that in $3+1$ dimensions.

I understand that in Newtonian Physics a point in $n$ dimensions, produces a gravitational field that drops off with distance at the same rate as a line in $n+1$ dimensions.  I also noticed that it seems that even when considering the equations for electric potential energy in the case of massive photons, the electric potential energy from a point charge in $n$ dimensions seems to drop off at the same rate as the electric potential energy from a point charge in $n+1$ dimensions.  I'm curios as to whether in General Relativity the gravitational field from a hypersphere in $n$ spatial dimensions and $1$ time dimension would, ignoring the difference in the number of dimensions, have a similar geometry to the gravitational from a hyper cylinder in $n+1$ spatial dimensions and $1$ time dimensions.

Basically my question is, similar to how in Newtonian Mechanics there's field lines, that make the force equation seem intuitively obvious, even if not field lines in GR, is there something that can not only make it intuitive how Gravity can be from spacetime curvature, but make it intuitively obvious how to derive equations in GR, even to a lay person?

Comment: Unfortunately... https://xkcd.com/895/

Comment: Fortunately... [A new way to visualize General Relativity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wrwgIjBUYVc)

Comment: @mmesser314 that is an improvement on the "rubber sheet", but still covers only a _very tiny_ part of GR.